# Backing up a single node Percona XtraDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, innodb, xtradb-cluster

I have a single node percona XtraDB Cluster.

Version:
Server version: 5.6.15-56 Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release 25.5, Revision 759, wsrep_25.5.r4061

All tables in the DB are using InnoDB engine and the database is partitioned.

The server is a RHEL 6 server and I want to upgrade it to RHEL 7. What I am planning to do is, stop mysql on the old server, shut it down, disconnect the disk (old and new servers are VMs), connect it to the new RHEL 7 server, turn the new server on, mount the disk, change mysql configuration so that it will point to the new filesystem. Sounds good on paper but will this actually work?

Comment: Single node cluster!!!!! No other options then...  you could have made the new node join the cluster n retire the old but disk!?! Btw why do u have single node cluster; instead just use percona server!!

Comment: There is a future plan to turn it into a cluster, that's why. The disk is huge and replication would take ages - can't afford that. That's why I am asking if reconnecting the disk to a different server will work.

Comment: Yes with respect to mysql, it should cause no issues for same versions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've tested this and the answer is yes. One small thing to keep in mind is that in RHEL 6 default filesystem is EXT4 while in RHEL 7 it is XFS and you will be mounting an EXT4 filesystem to a RHEL7 machine.